# Decompression routine very slow compared to C equivalent?

Tags: python, c, performance, audio, compression

I started off writing a simple audio decompressor in C. But now I've come across the same audio encoding within several different audio container types and decided I wanted to expand the decompressor and do more of a "universal converter", so I moved over to Python since I am much more familiar with it, and figure it will probably be easier for me to work with in the long run. The first thing I noticed when testing the Python equivalent, is that it's significantly slower compared to the C version.

The C version looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uint8_t BYTES_PER_BLOCK   = 16;
uint8_t SAMPLES_PER_BLOCK = 28;
uint8_t FLAG_END          = 0b00000001;
uint8_t FLAG_LOOP_CONTEXT = 0b00000010;
uint8_t FLAG_LOOP_START   = 0b00000100;

double coeffs[5][2] = {
    {          0.0,          0.0 },
    {  60.0 / 64.0,          0.0 },
    { 115.0 / 64.0, -52.0 / 64.0 },
    {  98.0 / 64.0, -55.0 / 64.0 },
    { 122.0 / 64.0, -60.0 / 64.0 }
};

uint32_t filesize(FILE *f)
{
    uint32_t filesize, offset;
    offset = ftell(f);
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
    filesize = ftell(f);
    fseek(f, offset, SEEK_SET);
    return filesize;
}

int clamp_s16(int32_t val)
{
    if (val > 32767)
        return 32767;

    if (val < -32768)
        return -32768;

    return val;
}

void decompress_adpcm(uint8_t *cmpbuf, FILE *outfile, uint32_t blocks_to_do, int32_t hist1, int32_t hist2, int loops)
{
    int     block_num;
    int     sample_num;

    int     predict_nr;
    int     shift_factor;
    uint8_t flag;

    int32_t loop_start = -1;
    int     l;

    short   scale;
    short   sample_byte;
    int     sample;
    int16_t outbuf[1];

    for (block_num = 0; block_num < blocks_to_do; block_num++)
    {
        predict_nr   = cmpbuf[block_num * 16 + 0] >> 4;
        shift_factor = cmpbuf[block_num * 16 + 0] & 0x0F;
        flag         = cmpbuf[block_num * 16 + 1];

        if (flag & FLAG_LOOP_START)
        {
            if (flag & FLAG_LOOP_CONTEXT)
            {
                loop_start = block_num;
            }
        }

        for (sample_num = 0; sample_num < SAMPLES_PER_BLOCK; sample_num++)
        {
            sample = 0;

            if(flag < 0x07)
            {
                sample_byte = cmpbuf[(block_num * BYTES_PER_BLOCK) + 2 + (sample_num / 2)];

                scale = ((sample_num & 1 ? sample_byte >> 4 : sample_byte & 0x0F) << 12);

                sample = (int)((scale >> shift_factor) + (hist1 * coeffs[predict_nr][0]) + (hist2 * coeffs[predict_nr][1]));
            }

            outbuf[0] = clamp_s16(sample);
            fwrite(&outbuf[0], 2, 1, outfile);

            hist2 = hist1;
            hist1 = sample;
        }
    }

    if (loops > 0)
    {
        if (loop_start >= 0)
        {
            for (l=0; l<loops; l++)
            {
                decompress_adpcm(&cmpbuf[loop_start*16], outfile, blocks_to_do - loop_start, hist1, hist2, 0);
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    FILE *cmpfile = fopen("C:\\test.adpcm", "rb");
    uint32_t cmpsize = filesize(cmpfile);
    uint8_t *cmpbuf = calloc(1, cmpsize);
    fread(cmpbuf, cmpsize, 1, cmpfile);

    FILE *outfile = fopen("C:\\test_c.raw", "wb");

    decompress_adpcm(cmpbuf, outfile, cmpsize/16, 0, 0, 3);

    return 0;
}
```

The Python version looks like this:

```
import struct

BYTES_PER_BLOCK   = 16
SAMPLES_PER_BLOCK = 28
FLAG_END          = 0b00000001
FLAG_LOOP_CONTEXT = 0b00000010
FLAG_LOOP_START   = 0b00000100

coeffs = {
    0:    {0:          0.0,    1:          0.0},
    1:    {0:  60.0 / 64.0,    1:          0.0},
    2:    {0: 115.0 / 64.0,    1: -52.0 / 64.0},
    3:    {0:  98.0 / 64.0,    1: -55.0 / 64.0},
    4:    {0: 122.0 / 64.0,    1: -60.0 / 64.0}
}

s16_t = struct.Struct("<h")

def s32(n):
    return int(((n + 0x80000000) % 0x100000000) - 0x80000000)

def s16(n):
    return int(((n + 0x8000) % 0x10000) - 0x8000)

def put_s16_le(n):
    return s16_t.pack(n)

def clamp_s16(n):
    if n > 32767:
        return 32767

    if n < -32768:
        return -32768

    return n

def decompress_adpcm(cmpbuf, outfile, blocks_to_do, hist1=0, hist2=0, loops=0):

    loop_start = -1

    for block_num in range(blocks_to_do):

        predict_nr   = cmpbuf[(block_num * BYTES_PER_BLOCK) + 0] >> 4
        shift_factor = cmpbuf[(block_num * BYTES_PER_BLOCK) + 0] & 0x0F
        flag         = cmpbuf[(block_num * BYTES_PER_BLOCK) + 1]

        if flag & FLAG_LOOP_START:
            if flag & FLAG_LOOP_CONTEXT:
                loop_start = block_num

        for sample_num in range(SAMPLES_PER_BLOCK):

            sample = 0

            if flag < 0x07:

                adpcm_byte = cmpbuf[(block_num * BYTES_PER_BLOCK) + 2 + (sample_num//2)]

                if sample_num & 1:
                    scale = adpcm_byte >> 4
                else:
                    scale = adpcm_byte & 0x0F

                scale = s16(scale << 12)

                sample = s32((scale >> shift_factor) + (hist1 * coeffs[predict_nr][0]) + (hist2 * coeffs[predict_nr][1]))

            outfile.write( put_s16_le( clamp_s16(sample) ) )

            hist2 = hist1
            hist1 = sample

    if loops > 0:
        if loop_start >= 0:
            for l in range(loops):
                decompress_adpcm(cmpbuf[loop_start:loop_start + ((blocks_to_do - loop_start) * BYTES_PER_BLOCK)], outfile, hist1, hist2)

def main():
    with open(r"C:\test.adpcm", "rb") as cmpf:
        cmpbuf = cmpf.read()

    with open(r"C:\test_py.raw", "wb") as out:
        decompress_adpcm(cmpbuf, outf, len(cmpbuf)//BYTES_PER_BLOCK, loops=3)

    return 0

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

This is what I get with a `profile` run:

```
         1647764 function calls (1647761 primitive calls) in 8.219 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    8.219    8.219 :0(exec)
        8    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(len)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(open)
   274624    0.344    0.000    0.344    0.000 :0(pack)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(read)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(setprofile)
   274624    1.234    0.000    1.234    0.000 :0(write)
        1    0.000    0.000    8.219    8.219 <string>:1(<module>)
   274624    0.625    0.000    0.625    0.000 test.py:105(s32)
   274624    0.734    0.000    0.734    0.000 test.py:108(s16)
   274624    0.875    0.000    1.219    0.000 test.py:111(put_s16_le)
   274624    0.266    0.000    0.266    0.000 test.py:114(clamp_s16)
      4/1    4.141    1.035    8.219    8.219 test.py:123(decompress_adpcm)
        1    0.000    0.000    8.219    8.219 test.py:178(main)
        1    0.000    0.000    8.219    8.219 profile:0(main())
        0    0.000             0.000          profile:0(profiler)
```

On my machine (Intel Core 2 Duo E8200 @ 2.67Ghz), the C version takes less than a second to finish executing every time I test running it, whereas the Python version takes about a whopping 8 seconds (as evidenced above) to finish. I test both versions with the same audio file, and there are no resource hogs or anything in the background that I'm aware of that might affect the performance of Python somehow.

Now, I see people suggesting things like "if you want speed, use C" all the time, and I certainly agree, but surely Python, at its best, shouldn't be THIS much slower than C?! I've been trying to optimize it as best I can, but I haven't seen any major improvements. The last tweak I did was to add a static struct for `put_s16_le`, which did help some, but still not a lot.

So is there any way to optimize the Python version, or am I stuck with a sluggish script here?

If it matters any, I'm using Python 3.4.3.

Comment: Perfectly normal that the Python version is way slower than the C one. I'm even surprised that Python is only 8 times slower for that.

Answer (score 2):

Wow, that is an impressively bad result, **only** eight times slower!

You have to think about it like this: for every arithmetic/bitwise operation that you do in python there's the same amount of computation as in C, but you get a python runtime that figures out which objects you combine, what the implementation of the operator is, then calls the py_object of the underlying Python interpreter's implementation, generates a new object to hold the result, and then assigns that.

That many levels of indirection are bound to introduce overhead. So, I'm really surprised the python implementation is only eight times slower. That probably means that there's room for improvement in your C implementation.

Comment: where did you get x8 from? I've only mentioned it takes LESS than 1 *second* (maybe less than a split second even) with the C version, whereas the Python version takes ABOUT 8 *seconds*. So it could be a much higher multiplier.